# Autoincrement problem

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem with autoincrememnted “id” column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391333/problem-with-autoincrememnted-id-column)

My db table looks like this pic. http://prntscr.com/22z1n Recently i've created delete.php page. it works properly but when i deleted 21st user next registered user gets 24th id instead of 21. Is it possible to put newly registered users info to first empty row? (In this situation 21st row)

In my registration form, newly registering user can write names of existing users, and be friends with them after registration. For this friendship i have another table that associates id of newly registered user and existing user.For this purpose i'm using mysql_insert_id during registration to get id for new user. But after deletion of 21st row during next registration process mysql_insert_id gave me number 21. but stored in 24th row. And put to associations table 21 for new user. I wanna solve this problem

Comment: Please do not repost. Edit your existing question if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You received the answer the last time you posted this question. MySQL maintains an internal counter that is incremented every time a new row is inserted into a table with an auto-increment column. The increment value does not go down when a row is deleted.

To make things work the way you want, you will need to avoid using MySQL autoincrement, and implement your own solution to create and increment IDs.

Answer (score 0):

`DROP` the field you are `auto_incrementing`
`ALTER` the table to `ADD` the field again with the same attributes

All existing rows are renumbered and the next auto_increment number will be equal to the row count plus 1

**WARNING**:

There really is no reason you would need to do this or `should` do this! If you have references to these ids anywhere, which I know you do from earlier questions - this can break every single link.

Comment: This is a disaster... please please don't do this. You will loooose all your referential integrity.

Comment: However, you shouldn't really need to do this - gaps should not effect your code at all

Comment: @Shef You are right I should have added that - however for what he wanted to do, simply make sure there are no gaps, it /will/ work but indeed if the id is referenced anywhere else there is no telling what will happen. I will edit my post with a warning

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_insert_id()` is a very very bad approach to get your id. You can always set the `auto_increment` value of your table, but I wouldn't suggest it. You should always do a `SELECT` of the latest record you insert based on some unique values, and order it by id `DESC` while limiting it to one result. Don't ever use `mysql_insert_id()`.

Comment: Is it bad even if you JUST inserted it and you just need to grab the autoincrement column for reference in a subsequent query?

Comment: @Connor Smith: Yes, if you have concurrent queries cannoning your DB at the same time. In which case, you will end up with some other dude's id tagged to you. ;)

Comment: thanks for the heads up, so in all queries that need to reference the last query should I do a subquery to get the MAX(id) of the recently altered table?

Comment: @Connor Smith: You should do a subquery like this `SELECT id FROM table WHERE name = 'somename' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1`. Notice, I am using `name` here, but you can use another or multiple other columns to fetch the most accurate record id, related to the record you just inserted.

Comment: Okay that makes even more sense than `MAX(id)` now that I think about it. So keep the value inserted into `name` as a variable and then fetch the id it was placed into later by referencing the same variable, got it :D

Answer (score 0):

It makes no difference - `mysql_insert_id` will return the autoincremented ID of the last inserted row. If the row gets ID 24, `mysql_insert_id` will return 24.

However, you can change the next value autoincrement will result it. Read up on it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html).